# Change Date() Return Value programatically in Classic ASP

Tags: date, asp-classic

I am doing some testing for my web application . And I would like to generate a fake server date , which will not affect the server date as it is production server eg:

```
Date()         // server date is 2013/05/21
```

What I would like to achieve is , after some programming...

```
Date()         // server date is 2013/02/28
```

How to achieve it in asp? thanks

Comment: How about replacing all your `Date` calls by your own function and returning the date you want to have (2013/02/28 e.g.)?

Comment: thanks. Just use a date string to replace the date() ?

Comment: Your web app may not have the necessary security credentials to change server date.
Even if it does, Windows is auto configured to synchronize server date time from external time server. So after setting a fake date, Windows will reset it back to the correct date/time.

Comment: Create your own Date function in Global.asa, e.g. MyDate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by the others most logical choice would be to write your own function. 
But I'd like to point a trick. 
In VBScript, you can re-write some built-in functions (unfortunetaly I've no official document about that at the moment). 

Luckily, `Date()` is one of them.
A user defined `Date()` function works.
I assume that you need a date 82 days earlier than the server date.

```vb
Function Date()
    Date = CDate(Int(Now) - 82)
End Function

Response.Write Date()
```